# Set access permission on an application as antivirus do

Tags: c++, windows, acl, dacl

I am trying to set permission on an application as read/execute only, I can achieve this by using c++ windows `SetSecurityDescriptorDacl()` function.

But after that admin can change it by right clicking on a file

> properties->security->advanced->Change Permission

But somehow antivirus prevents these charges on their application as shown in below image

[image]

Comment: You can remove admin rights, however admin can always re-take ownership.

Comment: @RichardCritten But how antivirus did this?
For example in Symantec antivirus the current owner is system, if I try to change the owner to administrator it popups Access denied error message.

Comment: Typically, this is done using a file system filter driver.

Comment: Hi thanks @HarryJohnston, can you please help me on this by little more detail... Sorry for bothering you

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/introduction-to-file-system-filter-drivers

Comment: A file system filter driver intercepts every file system request - including permissions changes - and can inspect, modify, or reject them.  In this case the file system filter driver would be rejecting the request to change the permissions on that particular file.

Comment: ... of course, the system administrator can always uninstall or disable the anti-virus software and *then* change the permissions on the file.  Or boot to Linux, or remove the disk drive and install it in a completely different machine, or ... at the end of the day, trying to stop the system administrator from doing something is almost always pointless.

Comment: Thank you very much will work on it and get back to you...☺

Comment: @HarryJohnston thanks....it works